# Javascript simple-form not loading

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I followed a tutorial step-by-step to create a form.
The user can select multiple company-cards. When a card is clicked, the background color changes by adding a "active" class. This is some super simple stuff i know - but despite i did everything in the tutorial, the javascript does not work. Hope someone can help me fixing this.

This is my javascript in assets<>javascripts:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".company-choice").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

And this is my view html.erb file:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
      <div class="form-profile">
        <h1>Write a post</h1>
          <%= simple_form_for @profile do |f| %>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
            <%= f.input :name, placeholder: "Hot to design a form" %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
            <%= f.input :status, collection: Profile::STATUSES, prompt: "Which status?" %>
            </div>
          </div>
<!--           <%= f.association :companies, as: :check_boxes %> -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label check_boxes optional">Categories</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="post[company_ids][]" value="">
            <div class="company-choices">
              <% Company.all.each do |company| %>
                <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" value="<%= company.id %>" name="post[company_ids][]" id="post_company_ids_<%= company.id %>">
                <label class="company-choice" for="post_company_ids_<%= company.id %>">
                  <%= company.name %>
                  <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                </label>
              <% end %>
             </div>
          </div>
            <%= f.input :content, placeholder: "In this tutorial..." %>
            <%= f.submit "Save your profile", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
          <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you probably should first try to remove the comment html wrap around this line `<!--           <%= f.association :companies, as: :check_boxes %> -->` so get rid if `<!--` and the closing `-->`

Answer (score 1):

The background color of the label is changing for me on click event. Do you have `background-color`set in this class `company-choice`? If yes then it won't change. In that case add `!important` in `baclground-color` property in `active` class.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".a").click(function () {
                $(this).toggleClass("active");
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        .active {
            background-color: red !important
        }

        .a {
            color: blue
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="1">
        <label for="1" class="a">Label 1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="2">
        <label for="2" class="a">Label 2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="3" id="3">
        <label for="3" class="a">Label 3</label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="4" id="4">
        <label for="4" class="a">Label 4</label>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This did the job. Thank you a lot! thumbs up.